# Which package(s) do you recommend for parsing XML and JSON in Java?

Tags: java, xml, json

Are there any packages you recommend for processing XML and JSON data?

Comment: please specify your question more... you might want to have a look at JAXB

Comment: For JSON, have a look at http://json.org/. Java already provides ways do handle XML...

Comment: Search for them individually.  Both have been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My votes are for [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) and [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial) - if you give your question more context we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) for JSON on Google Code.

Answer (score 1):

About XML. It depends of what you are willing to do with your loaded datas (how you want / need to process them), but if you are willing in the end to load XML elements into java beans, i'm a big fan of [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net), way simpler and quicker than anything else (imho).

You just have to annotate the fields that you want to fill when the XML content is processed.

The reading is jsut done with these two lines once the Example.class is correctly annotated :

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Example example = serializer.read(Example.class, new File("example.xml"));
```

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Blaise. Quite honest comparison, regarding your position. I don't know very well JaxB, and indeed both libraries are pretty close (with the big advantage of the "standardization" for JaxB). I really find SimpleXML a good tool, no jar / classpath problems, easy to use (as is JaxB), pretty fast, good error reporting when somethings goes wrong (XML element not mapped for example), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) as it can parse either.

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from google and and [FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)

Both are recommended